# facing issue on pipe filter in angular7

Tags: angular, typescript

facing error as The pipe 'shipperFinder' could not be found `*ngFor="let item of shipperList | shipperFinder : listsearch"`

i have created custom pipe as a syntax of angular and pipe class name declared in app.module.ts at declaration array section. when I use pipe name in

```
@Pipe({
   name: 'shipperFinder'
})
```

in html code facing error as shipperFinder pipe could not found

```
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="search here...." size="30" [(ngModel)]="listsearch">

<tr *ngFor="let item of shipperList | shipperFinder : listsearch">
                  <td>{{item.id}}</td>
                  <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                  <td>{{item.city}}</td>
                  <td>{{item.state}}</td>
                  <td>{{item.contact_no}}</td>
                  <td>{{item.email_id}}</td>
                  <td>

                    <a class="danger p-0" data-original-title="" title="" (click)="deleteuser(item.id)">
                      <i class="ft-x font-medium-3 mr-2"></i>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a class="success p-0" data-original-title="" title="" (click)="editUser(item.id)">
                      <i class="ft-edit-2 font-medium-3 mr-2"></i>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
```

pipe code

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { Shipper_master } from './shared/model/shipper.model';


@Pipe({
    name: 'shipperFinder'
})

export class ShipperFinderPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: Array<Shipper_master>, filterby : string): Shipper_master[] {
        if(!value){
            return [];
        }

        if(!filterby) {
            return value;
        }
       filterby = filterby.toLocaleLowerCase();
        return filterby ? value.filter((pro: Shipper_master) => pro.name.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(filterby)) : value;
    }
}
```

then in add pipe class name in app.module.ts

```
declarations: [
      AppComponent,
      FullLayoutComponent,
      ContentLayoutComponent,
      GenerateBlComponent,
      GenerateInvoiceComponent,
      ShipperFinderPipe
    ],
```

Comment: Is the template code part of AppModule? Or is it from another  module

Comment: I setup a stackblitz example with your filter ... works just fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cupdkk

Comment: if template code is not part of module the you might wanna put your pipe in exports array as well - `exports: [ShipperFinderPipe]`

Comment: I would recommend to check what indrajeet mentioned. Could you provide ur Project structure, to see where the component is located, that wants to use that pipe. regards